# Add taxonomy terms directly to node through SQL (term_node)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-nodes

How can I add taxonomy terms directly to a node through SQL?

I used:

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {term_node} (nid, vid, tid) VALUES ( " . $row['nid'] . "," . $the_term->vid . "," . $row['next_tid'] . ")" );
```

The values `$row['nid']`, `$the_term->vid` and `$row['next_tid']` are correct; but still no terms appear in the node.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing directly to the db, why not call the taxonomy_node_save() method instead: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_save/6

This way you can make sure you're not missing any additional steps that function does (even as small as 'flushing the term cache' at the end. :-)

Let me know if that works out!

Comment: Hi thank you for hint, but I use hook_cron and there I add terms to nodes. I looked this func. before, but problem is the code -> it would be very large for multivocabulary and another problem is old terms that must be add again to node. SQL is very simple and short, there is table where are only 3 values. Maybe I wrong. Have you some advice. My effort is rellored "Taxonomy Timer" for D6. I add my version to [issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/377450) of this module but has some problem with cron_hook resp. add terms.

Comment: I wonder if we misunderstood each other. I just meant that instead of the line of code that's "db_query(...)" you should have a line of code that's a call to that function: "taxonomy_node_save($node, $terms)".  I didn't meant that you should copy & paste the code of the function in your cron_hook, but just that you should call it.  Does that make sense?  When an API function is available to do what you want, it's better practice to use it instead of recreating its functionality yourself.  That way you'll know you're getting all the things right!

Comment: Ah, also just wanted to make sure you saw the code excerpt on the URL I gave above: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_save/6#comment-5749.  That's a function that may help you and it has as arguments the node, tid and vid, which you're using above in your SQL statement already.  :-)  Just wanted to make sure you saw that!

Comment: I understand what you say. But for $terms it must be array of news terms and old terms but why again load old terms. It would be lighter add only new terms. For tagg this must be array('tags' => array( $vid => 'tag1, tag2'), for other terms it shoud be array('term1, term2'). I saw source code :-) of taxonomy_node_save and there are sql statemets <code>db_query('INSERT INTO {term_node} (nid, vid, tid) VALUES (%d, %d, %d)', $node->nid, $node->vid, $tid);</code> these sql are same what I do but never saw my terms on node ...

Comment: When I start cron my hook_cron has a node object containing taxonomy objects, that is not problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I know that the source code performs the same SQL query as you were doing, but I was just trying to say that it probably does MORE than that query and you may be missing some extra parts when trying to re-create it.  For example, that function also has taxonomy_save_term(), and you may need that.  In either case, if you find a different solution, let us know! And good luck. :-)

Comment: Thank for your effort ;-) I will send my results here and drupal.org

Comment: So I have solution my problem. It was my mistake, because My values was not correct. I had bad value $the_term->vid see to [Mystery vid column in term_node table](http://drupal.org/node/114774#taxonomy-revisions). I thought it is vocabulary ID, but it is version ID :-). So the correct value is $node->vid and not $term->vid :-) So If you have in your vocabulary some terms and you want add your terms to a node, you simply do db_query('INSERT INTO {term_node} (nid, vid, tid) VALUES (%d, %d, %d)', $node->nid, $node->vid, $tid); and that's it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you guys talking about Drupal 7? In that case you should consider at least two more tables. CCK in Drupal 7 creates two tables for each field: `field_data_field_<fieldname>` and `e field_revision_field_<fieldname>`